# Choosing binary strings from an equivalence class with condition

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we define an equivalence class on binary strings divided on the Hamming weights of, aka the number of 1s in, the strings, so $$000\cong0000$$ $$110001\cong10001001$$$$110\ncong1111$$I want to find a way to choose a single canonical element from each equivalence class such that every infinite binary string ending in infinitely many 1s has exactly one of these canonical elements as a prefix, i.e. if you add enough 1s to any binary string that doesn't have one of these canonical elements as a prefix you will eventually get one of these canonical elements.

Comment: What does "them" refer to?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this goal is achievable?

Comment: No, but it seems reasonable. One approximation is that the empty string gets value d=1, "0" multiplies d by 2, "1" decreases d by 1, stop when d=0, and add that string to the set. Fits all conditions except that multiple strings can be chosen from the same equivalence class.